# Given: Log2=a, Log7=b. Find: Log 56.

Tags: logarithms

I don't know how to solve this. Can someone help me? How do I use the information above to help me find Log 56?

Comment: What is the prime factorization of 56?

Comment: Simpler exercises: find out $\log(2^3)$ and $\log(8\times 7)$.

Comment: its 2, and 7 right?

Comment: I need to solve it in terms of a and b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\log(56) = \log(7\cdot8) = \log(7) + \log(8) = \log(7) + \log\left(2^{3}\right) = \log(7) + 3\log(2) = b + 3a$

Comment: I got the answer correct. I think you made a mistake, because the computer said the answer is 3a+b. Thanks for the help though ZAF.

Comment: Might I suggest "\cdot" ($\cdot$) instead of a period to indicate multiplication.

Comment: Corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** $56= 7\cdot 2^3$

**Hint 2:** $\log (x\cdot y^z)= \log x+ z\log y$